# Combining mongodb codec registries in scala

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, scala-macros

I have two CodecRegistry implementation for a set of case classes. Most of them are created with macros. Now if I use the `RegistryOne` only, it works for set "One" - the classes from package `one`.

```scala
object RegistryOne {
  lazy val registry: CodecRegistry =
    fromRegistries(
      fromCodecs(..),
      fromProviders(..),
      DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY
    )
}

object RegistryTwo {
  lazy val registry: CodecRegistry =
    fromRegistries(
      fromCodecs(..),
      fromProviders(..),
      RegistryOne.registry,
      DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY
    )
}
```

Some of classes implemented in `RegistryTwo` are depending on package `one`. So I just included the `RegistryOne` into it. Now all serialization still works with `RegistryTwo.registry` for set "One". But for the classes of package `two` I get a runtime exceptions "Can't find a codec for class scala.Option". Seems like the `DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY` is not included in resulted registry?!

I have also `RegistryThree` and `RegistryFour`. At least for clarity and for future refactorings I would hold them separately.

How to combine the codec registries properly?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the error message is misleading. The macro for ADT main class also creates codecs for each subclass. If you also add a macro-created codec for one of them then the registry is confused and can't deserialize primitive things like `scala.Option`.